# Service discovery within AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, docker-compose, devops

I currently have a Redis, Postgres and a few Golang containers in a project of mine. I've got it all working locally on my machine using docker-compose.

```
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: redis/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - my-network
```

This allows me in my Golang microservice to use the container name to connect to the Redis container:

```
&redis.Pool{
    Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
        return redis.Dial("tcp", "redis:6379")
},
```

This all works perfectly, however, I want to place these containers within ECR and use ECS. I'm a bit confused as to how to identify my services and communicate with them in AWS. If I set the namespace to say `example` and then the service discovery name to `redis_service` within the ECS service is it as simple as using:

```
&redis.Pool{
    Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
        return redis.Dial("tcp", "example.redis_service:6379")
},
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After linking your containers you will be able to create connection between them the same way like it is done when setting it with docker-compose. It is described in AWS documentation for [Dockerrun.aws.json v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html)

> **links** List of containers to link to. Linked containers can discover each other and communicate securely.

That is if you are using Multicontainer Docker.

For more advanced/manual usage of ECS you may also be interested in this [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecs-service-discovery/)